# How to specify an external script in manifest version-3 for Chrome Extension

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

This is my manifest file -

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Title",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Title",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
        "script-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://use.fontawesome.com/9cd1c736ac.js"
        ],
        "object-src": "self"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "botScript.js"
            ],
            "matches": [],
            "extension_ids": []
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    }
}
```

The following is for manifest version-2 and doesn't work for version-3:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com ; object-src 'self'",
```

And I have tried the following variations as well -

```
    "content_security_policy": {
        "script-src": "'self' https://use.fontawesome.com/9cd1c736ac.js",
        "object-src": "self"
    }

    "content_security_policy": {
        "script-src": "self",
        "script-src-elem": "https://use.fontawesome.com/9cd1c736ac.js",
        "object-src": "self"
    },
```

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) says

```
Manifest V3 does not allow remote URLs in script-src of extension_pages.
```

So, does this mean, we can't use any external script in V3 at all?

Also, I get the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://use.fontawesome.com/9cd1c736ac.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: You can't use external scripts in Manifest v3. Download them and include them in your extension package.

Comment: The documentation you quoted already answers your question.

Comment: The script I wanted to use isn't a static one. So, downloading it is not an option.
I saw that the document said that external script is not allowed. So, I wanted some workaround, if there existed any. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to reference an external JavaScript in the Manifest V3 Chrome extension. If you publish it to the Chrome Web Store, the team will reject that update.

> In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be included in the
> extension. You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file.

Source: [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#:~:text=In%20Manifest%20V3%2C%20all%20of%20your%20extension%27s%20logic%20must%20be%20included%20in%20the%20extension.%20You%20can%20no%20longer%20load%20and%20execute%20a%20remotely%20hosted%20file.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#:%7E:text=In%20Manifest%20V3%2C%20all%20of%20your%20extension%27s%20logic%20must%20be%20included%20in%20the%20extension.%20You%20can%20no%20longer%20load%20and%20execute%20a%20remotely%20hosted%20file.)